# Whats a word for manipulating someone into doing stuff against you to where it is exactly what you wanted?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Like above, I saw a word before which was used to call someone or actions of someone who led other people into action which in their minds would cause them to win against you, and it is exactly what you wanted thus manipulating them into doing it.

TL;DR: Someone does stuff against you and they win, but, it is exactly what you wanted and the win benefits you in some way (eg. partial truth is uncovered).

Comment: In chess, it's a _sacrifice_.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth Its different, because it will not be evident that this benefits you in any way, where as sacrifice will become apparent in a couple of moves..

Comment: 'Offer oneself as bait' is an expression used hereabouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say that they were playing/planning/executing a **[Xanatos Gambit](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XanatosGambit)**.

> A Xanatos Gambit is a plan for which all foreseeable outcomes benefit the creator — including ones that superficially appear to be failure. The creator predicts potential attempts to thwart the plan, and arranges the situation such that the creator will ultimately benefit even if their adversary "succeeds" in "stopping" them.

*TVTropes*

So for example:

"John wanted to get Peter fired. As such, he planned a Xanatos Gambit by proposing to revitalize the HR system. If it succeeded, it would remove the need for Peter in the company. If it failed, John made sure that Peter would receive the blame and be fired for it"

However, it is not a single word, and is difficult to use as such.

Comment: Thank you, precisely what I was looking for but couldn't describe it properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's called **Reverse psychology**.

Comment: It is different from reverse psychology since you do not suggest anything to a person or group of people, or influence them in any other way. An example of what I am thinking about could be Media constantly bashing Trump and spreading bad things about him after he said certain controversial things, thus giving him free media coverage.

Comment: In your question, you state **manipulating someone**, but in this comment you say **do not suggest anything**. I am unclear on exactly what you want, @Snufkin.

Comment: Reverse psychology is asking people to do one thing because you know they'll the opposite.

Comment: @Chenmunka Yeah that what I thought his question was about, guess not. now I think he might mean propaganda, but who knows.

Comment: @davos I am not too sure how to explain it any better but basically you know a person or a group of people will go against you, and they will win, but it was all a part of your master plan. It is not reverse psychology since you do not suggest one thing to people hoping them to do the opposite.

Comment: How can you manipulate someone into doing something you knew they were going to do? Manipulation implies causality, somehow influencing people's actions.

Comment: @David K Maybe I should not use the world manipulate. Its basically you knowing something will happen, which everyone will percieve as bad for you, but it is what you knew would happen from the start and because you had accounted for it you made the moves to turn the bad situation around to your advantage beforehand, or you took steps to minimalise the impact of the bad thing on you. Its like a plan in which you want to loose, but loosing was the goal and the benefits of loosing are not evident to you.

Comment: Every time you try to explain what you're looking for, you end up contradicting things you said before. Perhaps a better approach would be to describe the exact context in which you want to use the word you're looking for--that is, if you have some essay in which you cannot decide what word to use in a particular place in a particular sentence, quote enough of what you have written and follow this with an explanation of the effect you wanted to get. Then we can try to figure out what would fit and what wouldn't.